# if the water pump breaks will it cause water in the engine.

Tags: power

mechanic tells me water pump went out..causing water in engine.  Symptoms: truck was running but low power, no acceleration

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the truck in question?

Comment: Do you mean water in the oil?  Because there's always water in the engine.  The water pump moves the water in the engine around and through the radiator.  What color is the oil when you pull oil the dipstick?

Answer (score 1):

Best guess based on your explanation: First the water pump quit/died, then engine overheated as a result and it remained running overly-hot for sometime thereafter, which (likely) led to head gasket failure, which resulted with coolant in the oil and the performance symptoms.

So yes, with the right unfortunate series of events, a water pump failure can result in coolant in the oil. But I believe it requires a key gasket failure somewhere in between. For what it's worth a failed water pump alone will not result in immediate performance symptoms, so [as @JPhi1618 is suggesting](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/12030/jphi1618), the symptoms suggest a more consequential wound to the engine.

While a water pump can begin this process, it is actually the overheating afterwards that does the damage.

Aside: I'm sorry that your 2017 is ending in this manner. Best of luck in 2018. Sincerely.